# Undefined cell value with dynatable table

Tags: dynatable

I'm trying gerenate a interactive table with dynatable. I followed the documentation instructions but i'm still getting "undefined" in all values of two columns.  I believe that `data-dynatable-ignore="true"` is not working and I want to know the right way to do it.

HTML:

```
 <table id="example" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="dynatable table table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th rowspan="2" data-dynatable-column="Unidade">Unidade</th>
                            <th rowspan="2" data-dynatable-column="Meta">Meta</th>
                            <th colspan="2" data-dynatable-ignore="true">Inclusão</th>
                            <th colspan="2" data-dynatable-ignore="true">Confirmação</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-dynatable-column="ValorI">Valor</th>
                            <th data-dynatable-column="%I">%</th>
                            <th data-dynatable-column="ValorC">Valor</th>
                            <th data-dynatable-column="%C">%</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
```

JS:

```
$('#example').dynatable({
        features: {
            paginate: false,
            sort: true,
            pushState: false,
            search: false,
            recordCount: false,
            perPageSelect: false
        },
            dataset: {
                ajax: true,
                ajaxUrl:  'https://api.myjson.com/bins/n4ecd',
                ajaxOnLoad: true,
                records: []
            }
        });
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/pvviana/fw69uLus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After waste a couple hours reading the dynatable documentation [documentation](https://www.dynatable.com/) I noticed that it's not posible yet. So i moved on [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) and i already created what i wanted.

I hope dynatable would improve your development possibilities soon.